# Loading in a .onnx file into javascript

Tags: onnx

I am trying to load in a .onnx file into a javascript session. The error I am receiving is TypeError: unrecognized operator 'ReduceL2', but this link https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/master/docs/Operators.md is saying that 'ReduceL2' is supported by onnx. I am guessing that it could have something to do with webGL not supporting it. Are there any work arounds or a better way to approach running a model in browser? very new to javascript.

Javascript Code:

```
async function runExample() {
  // Create an ONNX inference session with WebGL backend.
  const session = new onnx.InferenceSession({ backendHint: 'webgl' });


  // Load an ONNX model. This model is Resnet50 that takes a 1*3*224*224 image and classifies it.
  await session.loadModel("./pathtomodel");
```

Error thrown:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: unrecognized operator 'ReduceL2'
    at t.createOperator (session-handler.ts:222)
    at t.resolve (session-handler.ts:86)
    at e.initializeOps (session.ts:252)
    at session.ts:92
    at t.event (instrument.ts:294)
    at e.initialize (session.ts:81)
    at e.<anonymous> (session.ts:63)
    at inference-session-impl.ts:16
    at Object.next (inference-session-impl.ts:16)
    at a (inference-session-impl.ts:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to ONNX.js's [list of supported operators](https://github.com/Microsoft/onnxjs/blob/master/docs/operators.md), which is only a subset of all ONNX operators.  ReduceL2 is not on the list, but interesting that ReduceSumSquare is on the list, which seems to the same thing. (?)

Rather than waiting for them to implement ReduceL2 in ONXX.js, try either ReduceSumSquare or else try (pointwise) squaring your argument  and then calling ReduceSum.

Likewise, you could define your own ReduceL2() function that calls either of the above two operations.